# a quotation from the economist explanation

Tags: idiom-meaning

"if someone gave you a penny for your thoughts, would they get change?"

Could you explain the sentence completely?

Answer (score 1):

It's a joke.  "Penny for your thoughts" is an old idiom, asking for your opinion.  And there hasn't been anything of smaller value than a penny coin for decades, at least in the US.

Comment: Nor in the UK (the decimal halfpenny was withdrawn in 1984). Here, the phrase implies "You look thoughtful - what's on your mind?" and I suppose the quote suggests that the person's thoughts may not be worth much.